# Numeral system conversion in JS (error when typing a letter)

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, tostring, converters, parseint

I have a converter (numeral system). Everything works fine, but when I am trying to convert duodecimal (12) to decimal (10) there is a problem.
When I type "a" in duodecimals I have an error in the place of decimals - the output should be 10, but it's NaN (basically when I type a letter instead of a number (in hex too) there is this error).

```
    /* Calculation Board */

const config = {
    "binary": {
        "binary": v => v,
        "octal": v => parseInt(v, 2).toString(8),
        "decimal": v => parseInt(v, 2).toString(10),
        "duodecimal": v => parseInt(v, 2).toString(12),
        "hexadecimal": v => parseInt(v, 2).toString(16),
        "vigesimal": v => parseInt(v, 2).toString(20),
        "tetravigesimal": v => parseInt(v, 2).toString(24),
        "duotrigesimal": v => parseInt(v, 2).toString(32),
        "hexatrigesimal": v => parseInt(v, 2).toString(36),
    },
    "octal": {
        "binary": v => parseInt(v, 8).toString(2),
        "octal": v => v,
        "decimal": v => parseInt(v, 8).toString(10),
        "duodecimal": v => parseInt(v, 8).toString(12),
        "hexadecimal": v => parseInt(v, 8).toString(16),
        "vigesimal": v => parseInt(v, 8).toString(20),
        "tetravigesimal": v => parseInt(v, 8).toString(24),
        "duotrigesimal": v => parseInt(v, 8).toString(32),
        "hexatrigesimal": v => parseInt(v, 8).toString(36),
    },
    "decimal": {
        "binary": v => v.toString(2),
        "octal": v => v.toString(2),
        "decimal": v => v,
        "duodecimal": v => v.toString(12),
        "hexadecimal": v => v.toString(16),
        "vigesimal": v => v.toString(20),
        "tetravigesimal": v => v.toString(24),
        "duotrigesimal": v => v.toString(32),
        "hexatrigesimal": v => v.toString(36),
    },
    "duodecimal": {
        "binary": v => parseInt(v, 12).toString(2),
        "octal": v => parseInt(v, 12).toString(8),
        "decimal": v => parseInt(v, 12),
        "duodecimal": v => v,
        "hexadecimal": v => parseInt(v, 12).toString(16),
        "vigesimal": v => parseInt(v, 12).toString(20),
        "tetravigesimal": v => parseInt(v, 12).toString(24),
        "duotrigesimal": v => parseInt(v, 12).toString(32),
        "hexatrigesimal": v => parseInt(v, 12).toString(36),
    },
    
}

    /* Calculate sum */

const listFrom = document.getElementById("listFrom");
const listTo = document.getElementById("listTo");

inputPlace.addEventListener("keyup", function calculateInput(){
    calculate();
});

listFrom.addEventListener("change", function calculateFrom(){
    calculate();
});

listTo.addEventListener("change", function calculateTo(){
    calculate();
});

function calculate() {
    const listFromV = document.getElementById("listFrom").value;
    const listToV = document.getElementById("listTo").value;
    const inputPlace = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inputPlace").value);
    
    const fn = config[listFromV][listToV];
    document.getElementById("resultPlace").innerHTML = fn(inputPlace);
    
    if (document.getElementById("inputPlace").value == "" || document.getElementById("inputPlace").value == 0) {
        document.getElementById("resultPlace").innerHTML = "0.00";
    }
};
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: note `decimal` returns a number, while everything else returns a string. Otherwise, i don't see where your error would come from, can you maybe expand the snippet, so it produces said `NaN`?

Comment: I have added more code. I think that there is a little bit too much code to work in a snippet. HTML consists of 2 select lists.

Comment: Your value is `const inputPlace = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inputPlace").value);`, which doesn't understand `'a'`. `parseFloat('a')` results in `NaN`. I don't know why you have that `parseFloat` there anyways, when `fn` is supposed to do a more specific conversion.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice that. This code is a changed version of my other converter where that part is important.